# Ionic CSS Parallax scrolling not working

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I have attached a link to a working demo (this is not in Ionic) but as you can see it works fine.

Place the same code within the ionic tags

```
 <ion-content></ion-content>
```

it doesn't work at all.

I think it has something to do with the having the default scroll animation on

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YwGgom

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: You jsfiddle link is broken.

Comment: Hi sorry, try this: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YwGgom

Answer (score 0):

you can try `<ion-pane></ion-pane>` or use `is-scroll="true"` at your tag.

you can see it:
[ion-content](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionContent/)

[ion-pane](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionPane/)

[ion-scroll](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionScroll/)

Comment: Still cant get this working, have you got an example? I have tried adding the ion-pane instead of ion-content and also adding them both, with the pane within the content - no joy? Im stuck!